# Modify PHP array to only keep given keys

Tags: php, arrays

Given an associated array, I would like to remove all elements except those who are in a second array.  For instance, consider the following.  Yes, I could loop over either of the arrays and accomplish this, however, I have to believe there is a cleaner way.  Thanks

```
<?php
$array1 = array('a'=>'a','b'=>'b','c'=>'c','d' =>'d','e' =>'e');
$array2 = array('a','c','e');

//Desire array('a'=>'a','c'=>'c','e' =>'e');

//This obviously doesn't work, but am thinking there might be something similar
var_dump(array_intersect_key($array1, $array2));

?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var_dump(array_intersect_key($array1, array_flip($array2)));
```

Almost there. You need to flip the last array

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way using `array_filter()`. It uses a callback to see if the key is in the array of valid keys. If so, the callback returns true. Notice the flag `ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY` which tells `array_filter()` to pass the key to the callback instead of the value.

```
$array = array_filter($array1, function($key) use ($array2) {
    return in_array($key, $array2);
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
```

Edit: This only works in PHP 5.6+ as the third parameter to `array_filter()` in a new addition to the language.

Comment: John,  Is there any advantage using this approach over Exussum's?  It is longer, but maybe quicker.  I'll do a quick speed check, but usually feel a bit of speed is not worth slightly more complicated code.

Comment: Their solution is perfectly fine. As long as it make sense to *you* that's what really matters as you're the one who has to maintain the code.

Comment: Thanks John.  I will use the other solution, but I am messing with yours so I better understand how it works.  When using it, I get `Use of undefined constant ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY`.  I am using PHP 5.5.14.  Why do you think the constant is not defined?

Comment: That's kind of odd. My code isn't much different than an example in the manual. I also don't think that third flag is a recent addition to the function.

Comment: Ahh. My bad. This only works in PHP 5.^+ as that third parameter is indeed a new feature.